# The android application back to the initial state after minimized

Tags: android

I'm started learning Android development two days ago and already developed one app. This app is a flashlight application which the phone camera's flashlight will turn on when the user shake his/her phone based on the sensitivity level adjusted by the user and will turn off when finger cover the proximity sensor. In general, this app basically play around with phone sensors. The problem I'm facing in this application is the application will return back to the initial state after application is minimized but the flashlight is still on. Hence, i need your advice to make the application stick at the current state after the application minimized.

here is the APK file, https://www.dropbox.com/s/fapz30f1akre90k/com.example.shakyflashy_1.0.apk for you to try on your android phone to make you better understand the issue and here is the source code, https://github.com/mrzulkarnine/AndroidShakyFlashy

Thanks.